# Use the stream to collect on the map by the fields of the object

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private String surName;
private Set <String> domain;
```

Create a list of these objects

```
List<Person> persons = List.of(new Person(...), new Person(...))
```

how to make this method through Stream API

```
public Map<String, List<Person>> getDomainsWithPersons(List<Person> persons) {
    Map<String, List<Person>> domainsWithPersons = new HashMap<>();
    for (Person person : persons) {
        for (String domain : person.getDomains()) {
            domainsWithPersons.computeIfAbsent(domain, p -> new ArrayList<>())
                    .add(person);
        }
    }
    return domainsWithPersons;
}
```

so that the method just returns a stream, something like:

```
public Map<String, List<Person>> getDomainsWithPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        return persons.stream()...
    }
```

Comment: ```Person1, Person2``` are name, not a surname. Is that correct?

Comment: just Person objects

Comment: for instance, if you have ```List.of(new Person("Person1","Surname1", Set.of("gmail","microsoft")), new Person("Person2","Surname1", Set.of("gmail","ebay")),new Person("Person2","Surname3", Set.of("paypal","ibm")),
new Person("Person1","Surname2", Set.of("intel","microsoft")));```
how you wanted group by?

Comment: Something like this, but using StreamAPi
```Map<String, List<Person>> personsByDomains = new Map<>();
for (Person person : persons) {
    for (String email : person.getEmails()) {  // sets are iterable, we can just do this
        personsByDomain.putIfAbsent(domain, new ArrayList<Person>());
        personsByDomain.get(domain).add(person);
    }
}```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have a good way to do something like this using functional programming paradigms - or, at least, I don't think it does.

So, we can fall back on the old archetypical approach - iterate through `Person` objects, and for each one, add it to the appropriate lists in `personsByDomain` based on the domains of each of its email addresses.

```
Map<String, List<Person>> personsByDomains = new Map<>();
for (Person person : persons) {
    for (String email : person.getEmails()) {  // sets are iterable, we can just do this
        String domain = email.substring(email.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
        personsByDomain.putIfAbsent(domain, new ArrayList<Person>());
        personsByDomain.get(domain).add(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to do it using Stream API?
There is no need to format the list of domains) just group

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not so easy.

I have a answer to you, but, you might wait to get some answer with an expert.

For every email that a person has, I am creating a new object of person, just to put a single email. This is not the best solution

```
public class Teste {

    private static class Person {
        String name;
        String surName;
        Set<String> emails;

        public Person(String name, String surName, Set<String> emails) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surName = surName;
            this.emails = emails;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Name: %s, Surname: %s, emails: %s", name, surName, emails.toString());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> people = List.of(
                new Person("Matheus", "Rambo", Set.of("matheus@gmail.com", "matheus@outlook.com")),
                new Person("Felipe", "Esteves", Set.of("felipe@proton.mail.com", "felipeesteves@gmail.com"))
        );

        people
                .stream()
                .flatMap(person -> {
                    return person.emails.stream().map(p -> {
                        return new Person(person.name, person.surName, Set.of(p));
                    });
                }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> {
            final String email = (String) x.emails.toArray()[0];
            return email.substring(email.indexOf("@"));
        }))
                .forEach((key, value) -> {
                    System.out.printf("Domain: %s, people: %s.\n", key, value.toString());
                });
    }
}
```

And this is the output

```
Domain: @gmail.com, people: [Name: Matheus, Surname: Rambo, emails: [matheus@gmail.com], Name: Felipe, Surname: Esteves, emails: [felipeesteves@gmail.com]].
Domain: @proton.mail.com, people: [Name: Felipe, Surname: Esteves, emails: [felipe@proton.mail.com]].
Domain: @outlook.com, people: [Name: Matheus, Surname: Rambo, emails: [matheus@outlook.com]].
```